# Print label without any application (only sql)

Tags: sql, tcp, zebra-printers

Is it possible to print labels using not both c# application and sql,  but using only sql?

What can the function (part) of  tcp ip client (in c#) be replaced into (using only ms sql)?

Comment: I'm assuming you are working with a SQL Server database?

Comment: I don't think this is possible.